# Is it possible to use azure key vault for Storage account access key in Power automate

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, power-automate, azure-storage-account

I have a requirement to create an azure blob using power automate based on a trigger. I am using the access key to connect to the storage account. If I need to rotate the access key, what are the options to avoid the manual edit in the connection. Is it possible to use azure key vault to retrieve the access key and use it in the connection details of create blob component?

The password field in the azure blob storage connector in power automate does not seem to accept the variable value, Is there a workaround?

Comment: If you want to do what you’re asking about, you need to use the REST API’s rather than the blob actions.

Comment: I apologize for the delayed response. @Skin, Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to the Key Vault side of things, you can use the [Key Vault managed storage account key feature to list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/overview-storage-keys) (sync) keys with an Azure storage account, and regenerate (rotate) the keys periodically.

Please note that Key Vault Managed Storage Account Keys (legacy) is supported as-is with no more updates planned. For more info - [Manage storage account keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/overview-storage-keys#manage-storage-account-keys).

Additional Links:

[Manage storage account keys with Key Vault and Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/overview-storage-keys-powershell)
[Create SAS definition and fetch shared access signature tokens in code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/storage-keys-sas-tokens-code)

I hope this helps!